# Plotly: How to edit unified hoverlabel?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly, contour

I am generating a graph with two different contour lines. When I hover the mouse over the graph it compares a menu with the values of the two contours as in the image:

[image]

I obtained this result with this code:

```
# IMPORT
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as pyo
import numpy as np

# CONSTANTS SET UP
N = 11
x_min = 0
x_max = 10
y_min = 0
y_max = 10
fontsize = 18

# COLORS SET UP
blue = '#6683f3'
orange = '#ff9266'
black = '#212121'

# DEFINE THE MESH GRID
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, N)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, N)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# CALCULATE Z1 AND Z2
Z1 = XX + YY
Z2 = XX - YY

# DEFINE THE TRACES LIST
data = [go.Contour(z = Z1,
                   transpose = True,
                   name = 'Z1',
                   zmin = np.min(Z1),
                   zmax = np.max(Z1) + 1,
                   hovertemplate = 'Z1 = %{z: .0f}<extra></extra>',
                   contours_coloring = 'lines',
                   showscale = False,
                   showlegend = True,
                   colorscale = [[0, orange], [1, orange]],
                   line_width = 4,
                   ncontours = 20,
                   contours = dict(showlabels = True,
                                   labelformat = '.0f',
                                   labelfont = dict(size = 18))),
        go.Contour(z = Z2,
                   transpose = True,
                   name = 'Z2',
                   zmin = np.min(Z2),
                   zmax = np.max(Z2) + 1,
                   hovertemplate = 'Z2 = %{z: .0f}<extra></extra>',
                   contours_coloring = 'lines',
                   showscale = False,
                   showlegend = True,
                   colorscale = [[0, blue], [1, blue]],
                   line_width = 4,
                   ncontours = 20,
                   contours = dict(showlabels = True,
                                   labelformat = '.0f',
                                   labelfont = dict(size = fontsize)))]

# DEFINE THE LAYOUT
layout = go.Layout(plot_bgcolor = black,
                   hovermode = 'x')

# DEFINE THE FIGURE
figure = go.Figure(data = data,
                   layout = layout)

# IMPROVE LEGEND AND HOVERLABEL ASPECT
figure.update_layout(legend = dict(itemsizing = 'constant',
                                   font = dict(size = fontsize)),
                     hoverlabel = dict(font_size = fontsize))

# PLOT THE FIGURE
pyo.plot(figure)
```

In the layout definition section, if I replace `hovermode = 'x'` with `hovermode = 'x unified'` I get this result:

[image]

I would like to remove from this menu the first line that contains the information on the x. I honestly don't know where to start, I tried to consult the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-hovermode) but I did not get any clue.
What I would get (image manually edited):

[image]

A possible alternative would be to improve the appearance of the menu that appears in the first image:

- adding a unique background for the two contours
- adding a colored line for each contour

Version info:

```
Python  4.7.0
dash    1.12.0
plotly  4.7.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your desired output:

[image]

Then just include:

```
figure.update_traces(hoverinfo = 'name+z')
```

And, for both `go.Contour`, drop the `hovertemplate` parts:

```
 #hovertemplate = 'Z1 = %{z: .0f}<extra></extra>',
 .
 .
 #hovertemplate = 'Z2 = %{z: .0f}<extra></extra>',
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Some important details:**

It seems that `figure.update_traces(hoverinfo = 'name+z')` or similar setups will have noe effect if a hovertemplate has been defined in `go.Contour()`. At least that is what I've found to be the case. Please let me know if you make any other discoveries after testing this!

**Complete code:**

```
# IMPORT
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as pyo
import numpy as np

# CONSTANTS SET UP
N = 11
x_min = 0
x_max = 10
y_min = 0
y_max = 10
fontsize = 18

# COLORS SET UP
blue = '#6683f3'
orange = '#ff9266'
black = '#212121'

# DEFINE THE MESH GRID
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, N)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, N)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# CALCULATE Z1 AND Z2
Z1 = XX + YY
Z2 = XX - YY

# DEFINE THE TRACES LIST
data = [go.Contour(z = Z1,
                   transpose = True,
                   name = 'Z1',
                   zmin = np.min(Z1),
                   zmax = np.max(Z1) + 1,
                   #hovertemplate = 'Z1 = %{z: .0f}<extra></extra>',
                   contours_coloring = 'lines',
                   showscale = False,
                   showlegend = True,
                   colorscale = [[0, orange], [1, orange]],
                   line_width = 4,
                   ncontours = 20,
                   contours = dict(showlabels = True,
                                   labelformat = '.0f',
                                   labelfont = dict(size = 18))),
        go.Contour(z = Z2,
                   transpose = True,
                   name = 'Z2',
                   zmin = np.min(Z2),
                   zmax = np.max(Z2) + 1,
                  # hovertemplate = 'Z2 = %{z: .0f}<extra></extra>',
                   contours_coloring = 'lines',
                   showscale = False,
                   showlegend = True,
                   colorscale = [[0, blue], [1, blue]],
                   line_width = 4,
                   ncontours = 20,
                   contours = dict(showlabels = True,
                                   labelformat = '.0f',
                                   labelfont = dict(size = fontsize)))]

# DEFINE THE LAYOUT
layout = go.Layout(plot_bgcolor = black,
                   hovermode = 'x unified')

# DEFINE THE FIGURE
figure = go.Figure(data = data,
                   layout = layout)

figure.update_traces(hoverinfo = 'name+z')

figure.update_layout(legend = dict(itemsizing = 'constant',
                                   font = dict(size = fontsize)),
                     hoverlabel = dict(font_size = fontsize))

figure.show()
```

Comment: I like it! Almost done: in this way you do not apply the `hovertemplate` parameter. Is there a way to 'tune' the menu obtained by editing the traces' names, numbers formats or adding additional informations? What if I would use different number format, for example `'.0f'` for `Z1` and `'.2f'` for `Z2`? What if I would add a different unit, for example `Z1: 4 (m)` and `Energy: 4.28 (J)`?

Comment: @AndreaBlengino I'm not sure, actually. But I'll gladly take a look at it. But if you feel that my suggestion answers this question, would you consider asking the question in your comment as a new question in itself?